# Remover com regex tudo que estiver depois de dois pontos na query SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, regex

**OBJETIVO**

Eu quero remover com regex no SQL consulta tudo depois dos dois pontos, alguém pode me ajudar a montar esta consulta? Fiz várias tentativas, mas sem sucesso.

**Query normal**

[image]

**Remove com Regex**

[image]

**Resultado desejado:**

```
SRV
SRV
SRV
SRV2
SRV2
SRV2
...
```

**Tentativa:**

```
select regexp_replace(
hostname,'([^,]+), (\1(, |$))+', '\1\3')
from hosts;
```

Comment: Só vai ter um único `:` no campo?

Comment: exatamente, apenas um " : " dentro da STRING

Comment: Qual banco? Oracle?

Comment: Na verdade é um DB2 da IBM, mas geralmente as mesma sintaxes do ORACLE ou POSTGRESQL funcionam nele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se só tiver um único `:` no campo, uma alternativa é:

```
select regexp_replace(hostname,':[^:]+$', '') from hosts;
```

A regex tem o caractere `:`, e depois uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^:]` (qualquer caractere que **não** seja `:`), seguida do [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` (uma ou mais ocorrências). Em seguida temos o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`, que indica o final da string.

Ou seja, ele procura por `:` seguido de um ou mais caracteres que não sejam `:`, até atingir o fim da string, e substitui tudo isso por "nada" (na verdade, uma string vazia), que é o mesmo que remover este trecho.

[Veja um exemplo rodando](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed75f3/1) no SQL Fiddle.

---

Só para constar, a regex que você está usando [faz algo completamente diferente](https://regex101.com/r/4LW6LZ/1/).

Comment: Perfeito amigo, ficou excelente, muito obrigado!!